# SQL UNNEST requires alias?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm learning SQL and trying to understand UNNEST. On a table of FireBase events with the following schema:

```
event_params    RECORD  REPEATED    
event_params. key   STRING  NULLABLE    
event_params. value RECORD  NULLABLE    
event_params.value. string_value    STRING  NULLABLE    
event_params.value. int_value   INTEGER NULLABLE
```

This works:

```
SELECT params.key, params.value.string_value, params.value.int_value
FROM `...events_20181021`, 
   UNNEST(event_params) as params
```

Further when I run

```
SELECT *
FROM `...events_20181021`, 
   UNNEST(event_params)
```

I see columns like `event_params.key, event_params.value.string_value, event_params.value.int_value` (in BigQuery). But when I try

```
SELECT event_params.key, event_params.value.string_value, event_params.value.int_value
FROM `...events_20181021`, 
   UNNEST(event_params)
```

that fails. Why?

**Edit:** see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563922/1908650 for an example of UNNEST used without an alias.

Comment: `unnest()` requires an alias.  Otherwise, how can you refer to the unnested value in a `select`, `on`, or `where`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff that sort of makes sense -- but why am I seeing column names like `event_params.key` in my second query?

Comment: . . Those are structure references.  You should follow a BQ tutorial to get familiar with it.

Comment: as you can see from my answer  - alias is not required - unless you really need it - see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain
Will be using below CTE with my examples

```
WITH `table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('a', ('1',1)),('b', ('2',2)),('c', ('3',3))] params UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [STRUCT<key STRING, value STRUCT<string_value STRING, int_value INT64>>('x', ('666', 666)),('y', ('777',777))]
)
```

> Example #1 - simple SELECT *

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
```

this gives below [obviously expected] output

```
Row id  params.key  params.value.string_value   params.value.int_value   
1   1   a           1                           1    
        b           2                           2    
        c           3                           3    
2   2   x           666                         666  
        y           777                         777
```

> Example #2 - UNNEST w/o alias

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * 
FROM `table`, UNNEST(params)
```

result will be

```
Row id  params.key  params.value.string_value   params.value.int_value  key value.string_value  value.int_value  
1   1   a           1                           1                       a   1                   1    
        b           2                           2                
        c           3                           3                
2   1   a           1                           1                       b   2                   2    
        b           2                           2                
        c           3                           3                
3   1   a           1                           1                       c   3                   3    
        b           2                           2                
        c           3                           3                
4   2   x           666                         666                     x   666                 666  
        y           777                         777              
5   2   x           666                         666                     y   777                 777  
        y           777                         777
```

you can see now two additional columns named `key` and `value` (value being STRUCT with two fields respectively `string_value` and int_value) that came after names of respective STRUCT fields which got as a result of UNNEST'ing ARRAY of STRUCTs.
IMPORTANT: columns that starts with `params` are actually part of the REPEATED RECORD and cannot be directly accessed whereas those fields which are result of UNNEST'ing - can be directly referenced (unless some of them are array(s) by themselves in which case second UNNEST will be needed)

So, long story short - we can just reference them directly as `key` and `value` - for example

> Example #3 - referencing "inherited" field names

```
 #standardSQL
SELECT id, key, value 
FROM `table`, UNNEST(params)  

Row id  key value.string_value  value.int_value  
1   1   a   1                   1    
2   1   b   2                   2    
3   1   c   3                   3    
4   2   x   666                 666  
5   2   y   777                 777
```

> Example #4 - UNNEST with alias

Obviously you can provide alias for the UNNEST to avoid potential ambiguity - if there is another field named (for example) `key' so you want to be able to address this

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id AS key, param.key AS param_key, value
FROM `table`, UNNEST(params) param
```

with result as

```
Row key param_key   value.string_value  value.int_value  
1   1   a           1                   1    
2   1   b           2                   2    
3   1   c           3                   3    
4   2   x           666                 666  
5   2   y           777                 777
```

Hope, above will help you to get friendly with UNNEST :o)

You can read much more about `UNNEST`at documentation for [FROM clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#syntax) - go there and scroll a little down till UNNEST section

> Example #5 - case when alias is required

If you need to UNNEST simple array as in below CTE, the only way to reference flattened element is ONLY via alias

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, [1,2,3] params UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, [666,777]
)
```

for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, param
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(params) param
WHERE NOT param IN (2,777)
```

with result

```
Row id  param    
1   1   1    
2   1   3    
3   2   666
```

Comment: added `Example #5`